# how to add additional charge for order before 12 pm magento2.2.1

Tags: magento2, shipping-tax, custom-shipping-method, extrafee

i want to add the option for user have to choose the delivery time before 12pm and add extra charge for it in the cart.

Could you please help me for configure it, i have tried to create a condition in shipping rules but i dont have option for choose time.

if there is free extension please suggest me a link or guide me a way to configure it.

Comment: what shipping method are you using? shouldn't that be some kind of priority setting from the shippment provider?

Comment: What does it mean ? Is it something like next day priority before 12pm shipping method ? Can you please elaborate your requirement ?

Comment: just i want to provide give option choose delivery on next day or estimated date. user have to choose on them then based on that need to add some extra charge for it.